# Load More data on scroll down works when go to the full bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code it is working fine to Load more data on scroll down.
IT works when it hit the bottom but i want it to load more data before hitting bottom.

I did not tried anything because i'm stuck here.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            if($(".pagenum:last").val() <= $(".total-page").val()) {
                var pagenum = parseInt($(".pagenum:last").val()) + 1;
                var pname = "<?php echo $pgianame; ?>";
                var sname = "<?php echo $stianame; ?>";
                getresult('sellers_forum_page_posts_getresult.php?page='+pagenum+'&pname='+pname+'&sname='+sname);
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Just add like a margin value meaning         if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - 100){

Comment: it is not working at all after your code

Comment: Try this,         if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100 ){

Comment: same thing nothing happened

Comment: @AarzooeDeedeJanan Ferhat solution should work but by changing `==`  to `>=` .. The reason for that is in your code the bottom of the scroll is exact with the deference between window height and document height .. But after you try to decrease it by any number it's really hard for the scroll to catch the exact value .. Try to change `==` to `>=` and let me know if you have any problems

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef it do but it keep displaying same records again and again.

Comment: @AarzooeDeedeJanan Yes it should So you need to define a boolean `true/false` to stop that .. say `var is_ajaxed = false;` on the top of your all js code .. Then in if statement condition add  `&&  is_ajaxed == false` then inside the if statement add ` is_ajaxed = true` then in ajax success callback function return it to false ` is_ajaxed = false`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef can you please fix it and post it full????

Comment: please create the fix and post as answer i tried and fixed the issue as per your instructions